# Showing $12\Bbb Z<\Bbb Z$ as groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I'm having a bit of trouble answering the following question:

> The subset $m\Bbb Z = \{mn\in \Bbb Z\mid n\in\Bbb Z \}$ is a subset of the group $\Bbb Z$. By writing down the elements of the subgroups $4\Bbb Z$ AND $6\Bbb Z$, identify the intersection, $4\Bbb Z \cap 6\Bbb Z$, and show that this is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

I have worked out that

$$\Bbb Z = \{\dots , -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6\dots \},$$

$$4 \Bbb Z= \{\dots, -12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,16,20,24, \dots \},$$

$$6\Bbb Z = \{\dots, -18,-12,-6,0,6,12,18,24,30,36, \dots\}.$$

So $4\Bbb Z \cap 6\Bbb Z = 12\Bbb Z$.

but I am unsure about how to approach the second part of the question and show that  $12\Bbb Z$ is subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Do you know how in general to check that a subset is a subgroup?

Comment: $1$ divides $12$, so $12\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217173/let-m-n-be-positive-integers-show-that-m-mathbbz-is-a-subgroup-of-n-mat/3217179).

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: With no more work, you can prove the general fact that the intersection of any number of subgroups (even infinitely many, even uncountably many) is a subgroup. No need to make an *ad hoc* proof for some random special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0=12\times 0$, we have $0\in 12\Bbb Z$. So $12\Bbb Z$ is a *non-empty* subset of $\Bbb Z$.

Let $a, b\in 12\Bbb Z$. Then $a=12x, b=12y$ for some $x, y\in \Bbb Z$. Consider $a-b$. If $a-b\in 12\Bbb Z$, then, by the one-step subgroup lemma, $12\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$. But $a-b=12(x-y)\in 12\Bbb Z$.

Hence $12\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$.

There's nothing special about the number $12$ here.

Comment: Thank you, this has helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, @MaiMuopNguyen.

Answer (score 0):

Shaun's answer shows directly that $12\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. You can also argue that the intersection of two subgroups is always also a subgroup.